# How to Join Opportunity and User Object to get User Full User Photo URL?

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to write a SOQL query that will return Opportunity information and also get fields from the User Object where the User is the Opportunity Owner.  I am trying to pull in the user's profile photo URL.

The below SOQL does not work, but I am showing it to illustrate what I hope to do.

```
SELECT Id, Name, StageName, CloseDate, Owner.Id (SELECT FullPhotoUrl FROM User)
FROM Opportunity
```

How can I modify or write the SOQL query to return Opportunity information and fields from the User object who owns the Opportunity?

Answer (score 3):

An `owner` is a parent object of `opportunity` so you want to access `child-to-parent` relationship using dot notation.
Here is a query that would work:

```
SELECT Id, Name, StageName, CloseDate, Owner.FullPhotoUrl FROM Opportunity
```

you can read more about it here: [Understanding Relationship Names, Custom Objects, and Custom Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects)